# Parameters of the ground effect

Tags: aerodynamics

I'm trying to build a large, rotary-wing Ground Effect Vehicle. In order to calculate the necessary size of my props and motors, I need to know how much additional lift the ground effect will provide me with. My question is:

**What parameters will be most important for calculating the additional lift** produced by the Ground Effect at a given height? The propeller diameter? The surface over which the vehicle is being flown? The air temperature?

Answer (score 3):

A wing generates lift mostly by bending the flow if air blowing under and over it down. This washed out flow when not vacated promptly by the fact that the flight is near the ground will build up in layers of pressure waves which add to virtual density of the air behind the wing and add to the lift.

If you fly in cold temperature you feel similar thing, better lift, cleaner authority on the controls, because of the increase in density.

In planes the ground effect is highly sensitive to the geometry of the plane, location of the wings, if they are high or low, and of course the air's density and temperature.

Highpower computer simulation would be a good starting point.

Comment: Let me second this answer. If you're really trying to build an actual vehicle, there is really no reasonable substitute for high-power computer simulation. (Well, maybe wind-tunnel simulations, but those are more expensive.)